# Any way to specify the location of profile data

Tags: linux, gcc, gprof

The default the profile file is from the executable is run and the file is called `gmon.out`. Is there any way to specify a new location?

I'm using gcc 3.4.6 on i386/linux2.6

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18939913/694576

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Too badly, the environment variable `GMON_OUT_PREFIX` is not documented in the glibc. I got the following information from the web and tested on my machine.

if you set the environment variable `GMON_OUT_PREFIX`, then the output file is named as 
`${GMON_OUT_PREFIX}.[PID]`, the pid is the id of the profiled process.

For example:

```
GMON_OUT_PREFIX=mygmon; gcc -o foo -pg foo.c
```

the gmon out file is: `mygmon.12345`, assuming the foo process id=12345.

Comment: As stated below, you want to set GMON_OUT_PREFIX when running, not compiling?

Answer (score 10):

[jscoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54060/jscoot)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/464743/694576) worked for me, with the important difference of setting `GMON_OUT_PREFIX` at **execution** time, **not** at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem last week and I solved it in the following way. idea here is to change the process current directory to wherever you want to generate gmon.out file. file name can't be changed this way. It allows you to change where you can save the file.

```
#ifdef GPROF
                       /* so we can gprof */
                       if (1) {
                           char tmpdir[32];
                           snprintf(tmpdir, 32, "/tmp/%05d", mypid);
                           mkdir(tmpdir, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
                           chdir(tmpdir);
                       }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

To give a different file name to gprof:

```
gprof a.out gprof-foo.out
```

As to renaming them, set the GMON_OUT_PREFIX environment variable. I found this one by good ol' objdump on libc .... Naturally, the libc docs say nothing.

Comment: I'm really curious why this isn't documented