# Code compiled with profiling flag does not generate gmon.out

Tags: c++, c, gcc, profiling, gprof

I compiled a code with gcc using the profiling flag (`-pg`), but when I run the program no gmon.out is generated.
 I compiled a *test* code -- actually, the one from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826735/gmon-out-isnt-created-when-i-compile-with-pg-flag-with-g) question -- to see if the compilation flag & gprof were working and, yes, it worked.

To compile the code (named `xrttimetag`) the following line was used (here below I used `-I(...)` and `-L(...)` to hide a huge list of paths to other scientific libraries):

```
gcc -c  -o ./xrttimetag.o  -Wall --pedantic -Wno-comment -Wno-long-long -pg -fPIC -I(...) -DPACKAGE_NAME="" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="" -DPACKAGE_STRING="" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="" -DPACKAGE_URL="" -Dg77Fortran=1 -DgFortran=1 -DHAVE_CONNECT=1 -DHAVE_ACCEPT=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBM=1 -DHAVE_LIBDL=1 -DHAVE_LIBNCURSES=1 -DSIZEOF_LONG=8 xrttimetag.c

gcc -o xrttimetag xrttimetag.o      -L(...) -lswxrt -latFunctions3.3 -lcoordfits -lcoord -lephemeris -lhdinit_2.7 -lhdutils_2.7 -lape_2.8 -lcfitsio_3.37 -lreadline -lhdio_2.7 -lncurses -ldl -lm  -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../.. -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../.. -lgfortran -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lquadmath -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
```

I looked for symbols related to `gmon` on the generated binary and they look a bit strange for me since they are *undefined* :

```
readelf -s `which xrttimetag` | egrep "gmon|mcount"
 21: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
 74: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mcount@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
 41: 000000000040267c     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 call_gmon_start
 96: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
166: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mcount@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

On the other hand, the [*test*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826735/gmon-out-isnt-created-when-i-compile-with-pg-flag-with-g) code, I compiled with:

> g++ -pg test.cpp

And the search for "gmon|mcount" symbols give me:

```
readelf -s test | egrep "gmon|mcount"
 6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mcount@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
11: 0000000000400850    63 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 __gmon_start__
40: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS gmon-start.c
43: 0000000000400890     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 call_gmon_start
73: 0000000000400850    63 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 __gmon_start__
91: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mcount@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

We can that the "gmon" symbols are well defined for the _ test_ code and not for the _ xrttimetag_, but I don't really understand why. What am I missing?

Thanks.

PS: I saw the question [gmon.out is not written after compiling with gcc -pg -g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939913/gmon-out-is-not-written-after-compiling-with-gcc-pg-g) , and this one is not a duplication, unless I had completely misunderstood that one.

Comment: I had the exact same problem.. Excellent problem description & answer !

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are not passing `-pg` when generating executable.

i.e.

```
gcc -o xrttimetag xrttimetag.o ....
```

You should pass `-pg` option here too. I can re-produce the problem (i.e. symbols are undefined for gmon* calls) if I use `-pg` when compiling but not when linking.

From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html):

> -pg
>
> Generate extra code to write profile information suitable for the
>   analysis program gprof. You must use this option when compiling the
>   source files you want data about, and you must also use it when
>   linking.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Just to complement the answer: in my case, where I am using the good old GNU Make and didn't want to modify the makefiles, the "-pg" flag was added to the hold process through the (environment variable) CFLAGS (for the object (.o) generation) and LDFLAGS for the linking stage.